Google Re-Captcha Implementation is driving me crazy
I am still a novice and want to finalise my website but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to implement the re-captcha V3.
I have watched video after video but still not sure why its not working. When I add the g-recaptcha part to my Button class the form does not work. But once I remove it the form works.
Here is my code broken up in the different areas built as one of the videos guided:
JavaScript:
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>

<script>
   function onSubmit(token) {
     document.getElementById("contact-form").submit();
   }
 </script>

HTML Form:
<div class="rainbow-contact-area rainbow-section-gapBottom" data-sal="slide-up" data-sal-duration="400" data-sal-delay="150">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mt--40 row--15">
            <div class="col-lg-7">
                <form class="contact-form-1 rainbow-dynamic-form" id="contact-form" method="POST" action="mail.php">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="contact-name" id="contact-name" placeholder="Your Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="contact-phone" id="contact-phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" id="contact-email" name="contact-email" placeholder="Your Email">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Your Subject">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea name="contact-message" id="contact-message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group text-center">
                        <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="btn-default btn-large rainbow-btn g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="site_key" data-callback='onSubmit' data-action='submit'>Submit Now</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

PHP:
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $recaptcha_url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $recaptcha_secret = 'sercet_key';
    $recaptcha_response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

    $recaptcha = file_get_contents($recaptcha_url . '?secret=' . $recaptcha_secret . '&response=' . $recaptcha_response);
    $recaptcha = json_decode($recaptcha, true);

    $name = trim($_POST['contact-name']);
    $phone = trim($_POST['contact-phone']);
    $email = trim($_POST['contact-email']);
    $message = trim($_POST['contact-message']);
    if ($name == "") {
        $msg['err'] = "\n Name can not be empty!";
        $msg['field'] = "contact-name";
        $msg['code'] = FALSE;
    } else if ($phone == "") {
        $msg['err'] = "\n Phone number can not be empty!";
        $msg['field'] = "contact-phone";
        $msg['code'] = FALSE;
    } else if (!preg_match("/^[0-9 \\-\\+]{4,17}$/i", trim($phone))) {
        $msg['err'] = "\n Please put a valid phone number!";
        $msg['field'] = "contact-phone";
        $msg['code'] = FALSE;
    } else if ($email == "") {
        $msg['err'] = "\n Email can not be empty!";
        $msg['field'] = "contact-email";
        $msg['code'] = FALSE;
    } else if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
        $msg['err'] = "\n Please put a valid email address!";
        $msg['field'] = "contact-email";
        $msg['code'] = FALSE;
    } else if ($message == "") {
        $msg['err'] = "\n Message can not be empty!";
        $msg['field'] = "contact-message";
        $msg['code'] = FALSE;
    } else {
        $to = 'myemail2@mymail.com';
        $subject = 'Website Form Submission';
        $_message = '<html><head></head><body>';
        $_message .= '<p>Name: ' . $name . '</p>';
        $_message .= '<p>Message: ' . $phone . '</p>';
        $_message .= '<p>Email: ' . $email . '</p>';
        $_message .= '<p>Message: ' . $message . '</p>';
        $_message .= '</body></html>';

        $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: <myemail@mymail.com' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'cc: myemail2@mymail.com' . "\r\n";
        mail($to, $subject, $_message, $headers, '-f myemail@mymail.com');

        $msg['success'] = "\n Email has been sent successfully.";
        $msg['code'] = TRUE;
    }
}
echo json_encode($msg);?>


If the form doesn't submit at all, bring up your browser's developer console and see if there are any hints there.

"I have watched video after video" - why would you do that in the first place - when there is documentation available in text form, directly by Google itself? The fact that you probably have a client-side script error here that prevents this from submitting in the first place - on the server side, you have only made the API request so far, but you are not actually doing anything with the response.

And why would you make this script respond with JSON? JSON is hardly an appropriate response to a normal form submission; and you have not given any indication that you were submitting this in the background via AJAX or something ...?

@CBroe like I said I have very limited experience. I tried reading all the documentation but that did not help at all. and the question regarding JSON, I literally just implemented it as per the video guide I checked.
My knowledge is limited to basic front-end development so I am quite new to how the other stuff works.

Then start your with debugging, as has been suggested - go check if the browser console has any JavaScript errors to report.
